# how to align vertically an absolute element with a variable height above its parent?

Tags: html, css, absolute

I have a CSS layout which is actually like this :

```
|---------------------|
|                     |
|                     |
|                     |
|------------|--------| 
|            |   ***  | < article header
|   main     |--------| 
|  content   |        |
|            |        | 
|------------|--------|
```

On the right, I have a sidebar with an article element.
The article has a header with has an absolute position.
The height of that header is variable and changes across my website.
What I would like to achieve is to align the header vertically to have this :

```
|---------------------|
|                     |
|            |--------| 
|            |   ***  | < article header
|------------|--------| 
|            |        | 
|   main     |        | 
|  content   |        |
|            |        | 
|------------|--------|
```

Does anyone know how I can do that ?
Thanks a lot !

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/UhT5F/

HTML :

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="inner-content">
        <div id="main"></div>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <article>
                <header>article header</header>
                <p>article content</p>
                <footer>article footer</footer>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

actual CSS :

```
#content {
    margin-top: 10em;
}
#inner-content{
    max-width: 1140px;
    width: 96%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#main{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border-top:1px solid blue;
    width:65%;
}
#sidebar{
    float:right;
    width:33%;
    background-color:#DDD;
    padding:1%;
}
#sidebar article{
    position:relative;
}
#sidebar article header{
    border-bottom:1px solid blue;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Are you open to using JQuery?

Comment: @JamesKing Because, of course, [jQuery is the answer to everything](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: @JamesKing : I try not to use jQuery when possible... But I got the answer here below. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `top`, try using `bottom:100%`. You can use `margin-top` to fine-tune this alignment, say by a few pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Change the #sidebar as follows

```
#sidebar{
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    background-color:#DDD;
    padding:1%;
    margin-top:-25px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sentmca/UhT5F/3/

Comment: What if the height changes?

Answer (score -1):

Please check this edited fiddle...
with `minus margin and absolute display`..

http://jsfiddle.net/UhT5F/1/

Comment: @JamesKing than what is your answer to solve this.. any answer will be affected by its height.. do think before votedown...

Comment: The question does state that the height is variable and therefore this answer doesn't solve it

Comment: @JamesKing thats why I am asking you the right answer.. If you can find problem in my answer than you must know the right answer as well..